# magento 2 version of getSingleton

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, m2e, singleton

In Magento 2 we are using dependency injection in replace of old style getModel, getHelper etc

I have a particular class that i find i am injecting in a lot of places which holds some general configuration values i need across lots of classes.

I want to know how to make this a singleton like in Magento 1 we did getSingleton.

Answer (score 4):

if you don't explicitly configure it otherwise, the same object is shared everywhere. So basically, the same as a getSingletion in magento1

You can still configure constructor arguments not to be shared (if needed) in the di.xml like described here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Filesystem" shared="false">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="adapter" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Magento\Filesystem\Adapter\Local</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

in most cases, however, I think a factory is more suited to create a new object inside your class